# Ignore "cannot find module" error on typescript

Tags: import, module, typescript

Can the Typescript compiler ignore the `cannot find module 'x'` error on import expressions such as:

```
//How to tell the compiler that this module does exists
import sql = require('sql');
```

There are multiple npm libraries such as [node sql](https://github.com/brianc/node-sql) that doesn't have existing typings

Is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore this error other than creating a new definition file with the `declare module x ...` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just want to bypass the compiler, you can create a .d.ts file for that module, for instance, you could create a sql.d.ts file and inside have this:

```
declare module "sql" {
  let _sql: any;
  export = _sql;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
how would the declaration look like for this module please:
https://github.com/christophergregory/shopify-node-api/blob/master/lib/shopify.js#L257

I tried declaring it but I get ```Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'shopify-node-api' cannot be found.```

Comment: Is there no other way of getting round these errors without creating a separate dummy definition file for every module?

Comment: Also that just didn't work. I got this error: `Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'express' resolves to an untyped module at '.../node_modules/express/index.js', which cannot be augmented`

Comment: How does this approach work if the import is a `@foo/bar` import?

Answer (score 67):

As of TypeScript 2.6 (released on Oct 31, 2017), now there is [a way to ignore all errors from a specific line](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) using `// @ts-ignore` comments before the target line.

[The mendtioned documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) is succinct enough, but to recap:

```
// @ts-ignore
const s : string = false
```

disables error reporting for this line.

However, this should only be used as a last resort when fixing the error or using hacks like `(x as any)` is much more trouble than losing all type checking for a line.

As for specifying certain errors, the current (mid-2018) state is discussed [here, in Design Meeting Notes (2/16/2018) and further comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22011), which is basically

> "no conclusion *yet*"

and strong opposition to introducing this fine tuning.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Also got Eslint enabled, so had to add another comment above to enable the `@ts-ignore`. Just add `eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment` above it and it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved This**
By default @ts-check looks for definitions of a module, either its your own code or external libraries.

> Since we are not using ES6 style modules, then we must we are using
>   commonjs, check my jsconfig.json file for help.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "typeAcquisition": { "enable": true }
}
```