# How to import a single-spa in-browser utility module into a TypeScript parcel project

Tags: typescript, single-spa

I have 3 TypeScript projects below:

1. root-config
2. parcel, let us call it `my-app`
3. in-browser utility module, let us call it `api`

All the projects above were generated using the `create-single-spa` command.

In the `api/src/lomse-api.ts` file, I'm exporting the `fetchPeople` module as shown below:

```
export { fetchPeople } from "./PeopleApi.ts";
```

According to the [single-spa documentation](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#utility-modules-styleguide-api-etc), given my `orgName` is `lomse` and `projectName` is `api`, I should be able to import the `fetchPeople` module into `my-app` (a parcel app)  like this:

```
import { fetchPeople } from '@lomse/api'
```

Since `my-app` project is a TypeScript project, the statement above is definitely going to throw the error below:

```
Cannot find module '@lomse/api' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is a TypeScript error, not a JavaScript or single-spa error. Here are options for what you need to do:

1. Publish your utility module to a registry (types are optional since TS can infer from the source, though types are better) using a Node.js-compatible module format (UMD, Commonjs). Then install it into each other microfrontend's node_modules. Since it's a webpack external, the version in node_modules will only be used for typescript compilation but not for execution in the browser. However this may require a second build and could create problems dues to interop differences.
2. You could publish only the module types, whether as an individual package or together with other microfrontend's typings.
3. Mock the utility module's types, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357563/2554793).

Source:

- https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa/issues/609#issuecomment-665132965
- https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa.js.org/issues/361#issuecomment-737259914