# How can I import types/interfaces from a SingleSpa utility module to a Typescript based Micro frontend react app

Tags: typescript-typings, micro-frontend, single-spa, type-declaration, single-spa-react

I'm setting up Micro Frontend architecture using [SingleSpa](https://single-spa.js.org/). My apps(micro frontends) are setup using Typescript. As I'm in need of extracting out some common/shareable types/interfaces. So, each app can consume these type(s) using SingleSpa provided [Utility modules](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#utility-modules-styleguide-api-etc). Not sure if this is the best way to do it but that's how I thought to proceed.

I do have a bit of understanding that in order to consume Utility module inside a Micro frontend. I need to create a declaration file`(.d.ts)` in the app. Like in my case, if I need to import type `SomeType` from utility then I need to do something like below in the app `declaration.d.ts`. Doing this makes the VSCode intellisense acknowledge that utility does have `SomeType` available.

```
// /somewhere-in-app/declaration.d.ts

declare module '@organization/types-utility' {
   export type SomeType;
}
```

Now here is the problem, if this is how I declare the module in each of the app declaration`(.d.ts)` file then how can I achieve the purpose of shareable types using SingleSpa utility module. As, it looks redundant that each app is maintaining its own declaration file for common types to be imported.

Currently I tried importing the type as below:

```
import { type SomeType } from '@organization/types-utility';
```

or

```
import type { SomeType } from '@organization/types-utility';
```

and consumed through following ways:

**Option 1** (not working)

```
const someVariable: SomeType
```

it throws error

```
Cannot use namespace 'SomeType' as a type.
```

**Option 2** (suppresses the ts warning but do not suggest available props in SomeType)

```
const someVariable = {} as typeof SomeType
```

it makes the error disappear but the VSCode intellisense do not suggest available props inside `SomeType`. :(

**Looking for a better solution/approach**

Sharing the module with SingleSpa utility works but I'm not sure if importing the `types` through  this approach is the way to go. May be I should try something different. Open to any viable suggestions from the community.

**Other things in my mind**

Third party `npm` packages bundled with related modules and types through their own declaration`(.d.ts)` files. Wondering, do I have to publish my own private npm `types-utility` package? Unfortunately, I'm not looking forward to this approach yet unless there is no other option.

Feel free to ask more about the problem or if something more is needed to help understand better.

**Similar Issue**

Found somewhat related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66399978/how-to-import-a-single-spa-in-browser-utility-module-into-a-typescript-parcel-pr)